# Is it possible to use Burp to show hidden AngularJS elements, that are hidden using "ngHide"?

Tags: appsec, burp-suite, angularjs

I’m performing an audit of an AngularJS application that uses Angular's ngShow and ngHide to show and hide elements on a page. **Is it possible to use Burp Proxy, Burp Macros, or another tool to automatically show or hide elements with the “ng-hide” class?**

I’ve tried the normal Response Modification options in Burp without success:
[image: burp1]

I've also tried combinations of the following Burp Proxy rules with no luck:
[image: burp2]

Comment: Please show a screenshot of "Original Response" and "Edited Response" to show us why it could not be working.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show the original source, I no longer have access, but I will say: once all the replaces are in there, viewing the source of the page I did see "ng-hide" and changed to "ng-show", but they don't actually show up.

I think the problem is a more fundamental question specific to how AngularJS handles that transition, not specific to my application. My theory is that angular might perform some "transition"? of showing and hiding after the page has loaded, and since Burp doesn't have access to the DOM replacing stuff just breaks things instead of what I want to happen.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I might dig into it if not